# Piechart of agents with special characteristics

Tags: anylogic

I have three sources that generate packages. Each source gets a special tyo assigned to it:

```
agent.p_type = 0;
agent.p_type = 1;
agent.p_type = 2;
```

After processing a package, I want to formulate a command in the block: "moveByCrane", which gives me the number of packages by specific type in a pie chart.

My attempt was this:

```
auftrag1 = count(agent.p_type == 0);
```

order1 is a variable that is then called in the pie chart.

However, I get an error message that it doesn't work that way. What is the problem?
[image: pie chart]

My error message is: [image: error message]

It appears in "MovebyCrane"

My Code is:

[image: code in MovebyTrain]

Comment: What is the error msg? Always show full details, hard to help without the full picture :)

Comment: The error message is: The method count (iterable <T>, Predicate <? super T>) in the type UtilitiesCollection is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

Comment: And where is it thrown? Which line of your model code does it refer to? Best update the original questions and show more screenshots to make this more understandable (already very good effort, just not quite understandable).

Comment: Answer below. Quick general tip: It seems you do not really understand coding and Java (which is totally fine and normal). Best start learning the basics of OOP, there are Java-for-AnyLogic courses out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. turn your `auftragX` variables into type `int`
2. in your "on at enter" code in `MovebyCrane`, count each passing agent as below

code:

```
if (agent.p_Type == 0) {
    auftrag1 ++;
} else if (agent.p_Type == 1) {
    auftrag2 ++;
} else if (agent.p_Type == 2) {
    auftrag3 ++;
} else {
    error("dsafsdf");
}
```

3. do all AnyLogic tutorials, they go deep into how to use charts correctly :)

Comment: amazing, thank you a lot!! and yes you are totally right - I am working on it:)